# Multiply Strings - [leetcode] The code works perfectly fine on computer but not on the website

Tags: c

For the "multiply strings" challenge on LeetCode, I wrote this code in C;

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char  *multiply(char *num1, char *num2){
    int num1_len = strlen(num1);
    int num2_len = strlen(num2);
    int *multiplication;

    int total_len = num1_len+num2_len;
    multiplication = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*total_len);


    int i, j, k, l;

    for(i = 0; i<total_len; i++){
        multiplication[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i = num1_len-1, k = total_len-1; i>= 0; i--, k--){
        for(j = num2_len-1, l = 0; j>= 0; j--, l++){
            multiplication[k-l] += (num1[i]-48)*(num2[j]-48);
            if(multiplication[k-l]>= 10){
                int number = multiplication[k-l];
                int carry = number%10;
                multiplication[k-l] = carry;
                multiplication[k-l-1] += (number-carry)/10;
            }
        }
    }

    char *multiplication_result;
    multiplication_result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    int start_index;
    for(i = 0; i<total_len; i++){
        if(multiplication[i] != 0){
            start_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i = start_index, j = 0; i<total_len; i++, j++){
        multiplication_result[j] = multiplication[i]+48;
        multiplication_result = (char *)realloc(multiplication_result, j+2);
    }
    return multiplication_result;
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my computer. I tested it with different strings and each test gave the expected output. However every time I run the exact same code on leetcode I get a runtime error. It gives the following error:

> > =================================================================
> > ==33==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000092 at pc 0x55d553422e2b bp 0x7fff8bada4d0 sp
> > 0x7fff8bada4c0 READ of size 1 at 0x602000000092 thread T0
> > #2 0x7fcef1ab10b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2) 0x602000000092 is located 0
> > bytes to the right of 2-byte region [0x602000000090,0x602000000092)
> > allocated by thread T0 here:
> > #0 0x7fcef26f6ffe in __interceptor_realloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dffe)
> > #3 0x7fcef1ab10b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2) Shadow bytes around the
> > buggy address:   0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> > 00 00 00 00   0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> > 00 00 00   0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> > 00 00   0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> > 00   0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 02 fa fa fa 02 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa fd fa
> > =>0x0c047fff8010: fa fa[02]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa   0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> > 0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> > 0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> > 0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> > 0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa Shadow
> > byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
> > Addressable:           00   Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06
> > 07    Heap left redzone:       fa   Freed heap region:       fd
> > Stack left redzone:      f1   Stack mid redzone:       f2   Stack
> > right redzone:     f3   Stack after return:      f5   Stack use after
> > scope:   f8   Global redzone:          f9   Global init order:
> > f6   Poisoned by user:        f7   Container overflow:      fc   Array
> > cookie:            ac   Intra object redzone:    bb   ASan internal:
> > fe   Left alloca redzone:     ca   Right alloca redzone:    cb
> > Shadow gap:              cc
> > ==33==ABORTING

I am not too familiar with leetcode as I just started and I am not too good at reading these error messages. So what causes this problem?

Comment: This is a typical symptom of *undefined behaviour*. You have `multiplication_result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` which allocates **1 byte** yet you index it by using `multiplication_result[j]`. Note that you also have a memory leak if the caller does not `free(multiplication_result)`.

Comment: ...mybad I have noticed the `realloc` now. But if this is a text string (you add `48`) then it has no NUL-terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (potentially) two problems in your code. The first one (definite) is that you never add a `nul` terminator to your `multiplication_result` string. To fix this, simply add the following line after your final `for` loop and immediately before the `return` statement:

```c
multiplication_result[j] = '\0';
```

The second (possible) issue – flagged as a warning by the clang-cl compiler – is that you have a potentially uninitialized value for the `start_index` variable at the start of that final `for` loop. To fix this, just give that an initial value (`0`) at the time of its declaration:

```c
int start_index = 0;
```

From what I can tell, this second issue will only be a problem if both input strings represent zero (but I wouldn't like to bet any money on that).

---

Also, as a possible improvement, the following line:

```c
multiplication[k - l - 1] += (number - carry) / 10;
```

can be simplified to just:

```c
multiplication[k - l - 1] += number / 10;
```

because the the quotient of an integer division, `i/n` will be the same as the result of performing the division *after* subtracting the (potential) remainder of that division (that's how the `%` operator works).

Comment: Yes, this seemed to fix the problem. Thank you so much! Though I am curious about why not having the nul terminator causes a problem?

Comment: Because, without explicitly adding that `nul` terminator, the rest of the character buffer will contain uninitialized (garbage) values. And C-strings **must** have that `nul` terminator.